# Grabbing specified words using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get a certain words using `re` as my code reads and opens a list of files.

```
import re
id_list = []
my_str = 'Error: Unable to version with file_id `a123-4567-89001` on server `serverA`'
match = re.search("file_id(.*)$", my_str)
if match:
    out_list.append(match.group(1))

print list(set(id_list))
# Result : [' `a123-4567-89001` on server `serverA`']
```

While I seems to get the id within the back-ticks, but at the same time I am getting all other words after the `file_id` word

How can I code to just grab the id code such that the result is `a123-4567-89001`?

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Txfi3T).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Post the snippet as an answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest matching any 0+ whitespace chars after `file_id` and a backtick, and then match and *capture* any 0+ chars other than backticks into Group 1:

```
file_id\s*`([^`]*)`
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3bpLj/1)

**Details**

- `file_id` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `` ` `` - a backtick
- `` ([^`]*) `` - any 0+ chars other than a backtick
- `` ` `` - a backtick

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Txfi3T)

```
import re
id_list = []
my_str = 'Error: Unable to version with file_id `a123-4567-89001` on server `serverA`'
match = re.search(r"file_id\s*`([^`]*)`", my_str)
if match:
    id_list.append(match.group(1))

print list(set(id_list))
# => ['a123-4567-89001']
```

Comment: Here is a bit [simpler code demo](https://ideone.com/DbqSJt) to get the first match.

Comment: Cool, I was trying to look for something similar earlier but it is more of inputting in the expression and test string.

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern "file_id `(.*?)` on server `(.*?)`"

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("file_id `(.*?)` on server `(.*?)`", 'Error: Unable to version with file_id `a123-4567-89001` on server `serverA`')
[('a123-4567-89001', 'serverA')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
my_str = 'Error: Unable to version with file_id `a123-4567-89001` on server `serverA`'
the_id = re.findall('(?<=file_id\s\`)[a-z0-9-]+(?=\`)', my_str)[0]
```

Output:

```
'a123-4567-89001'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two cases where there are backticks in the `string`, you want to extract the one that comes after `file_id`.

To do this, we search for `file_id`, then match a whitespace (`\s`) character, then a backtick, then capture everything up to the next backtick.

To capture "everything up to" we can use a `lazy quantifier` - this essentially just involves a `*?` which means match everything preceding this up to whatever comes after the `?`.

So, putting this into a regex, we get:

```
file_id\s`(.*?)`
```

which works great:

```
>>> match = re.search("file_id\s`(.*?)`", my_str)
>>> match.group(1)
'a123-4567-89001'
```